# javascript window.open can't go back to parent folder

Tags: javascript, window

I'm trying to open a pdf that is located in the parent folder. I have no problem opening a pdf in the current directory or a child directory. However can't load the parent folder.

```
aLink.click(function(){
     var pdf = "/../test.pdf";
     window.open(pdf);
});
```

after running it we get Cannot GET /test.pdf.
Seems like it doesn't recognize /../ (accessing parent directory) Any help?

Answer (score 2):

Write it this way:

```
var pdf = "../test.pdf";
```

Without the first slash

Answer (score 1):

Many servers these days disable the ability to use relative links to access parent elements by default due to certain exploits where sloppy code can be used to expose your account level login information.  Instead, you should use a base url so you can make your calls top-down.

```
var base_url = window.location.origin;
aLink.click(function(){
  var pdf = base_url+"/folder/test.pdf";
  window.open(pdf);
});
```